# DropNetRT Dropbox JSON deserializer seems to be using the wrong sort of object?

Tags: c#, json.net, dropbox-api, dropnet

I'm using DropNetRT to try to integrate with Dropbox, but am consistently getting errors at the point of deserializing JSON responses from the Dropbox API. Without further ado:

The exception thrown is

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException occurred
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'entries[0][1]', line 1, position 202.
  Source=Newtonsoft.Json
  LineNumber=1
  LinePosition=202
  Path=entries[0][1]
```

The exception is thrown on `var deltaResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeltaPageInternal>(responseBody);`

What's `responseBody`? It's this guy (slightly simplified for everyone's convenience:

```
{   
    "has_more": true, 
    "cursor": "BLAGHABLAGAbigDarn-StringTHing123", 
    "entries": 
    [
        ["/exampleFile.pdf", {"revision": 1, "rev": "1131aa664", "thumb_exists": false, "bytes": 249159, "modified": "Mon, 12 Aug 2013 18:55:30 +0000", "client_mtime": "Mon, 12 Aug 2013 18:55:30 +0000", "path": \"/exampleFole.pdf\", "is_dir": false, "icon": "page_white_acrobat", "root": "dropbox", "mime_type": "application/pdf", "size": "243.3 KB"}],
        ["/examplefolder", {"revision": 2, "rev": "2131aa664", "thumb_exists": false, "bytes": 0, "modified": "Tue, 13 Aug 2013 17:30:35 +0000", "path": "/examplefolder", "is_dir": true, "icon": "folder_user", "root": "dropbox", "size": "0 bytes"}]
    ], 
    "reset": true
}
```

My suspicion is that the model `DeltaPageInternal` is to blame, since entries[0][1] is not in fact what the model seems to imply:

```
internal class DeltaPageInternal
{
    public string Cursor { get; set; }
    public bool Has_More { get; set; }
    public bool Reset { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone else have this problem? It seems like it should be pretty prevalent, given the type of the response gotten from Dropbox... Am I calling an old API version or something?

Thanks in advance for any expertise, as usual.

Comment: Does the `responseBody` string actually have backslashes like that, or did you copy this string from the debugger in Visual Studio?  If it has backslashes, that usually indicates it has been double-serialized.

Comment: @BrianRogers I copied it from the debugger, shall I remove the escapes?

Comment: Yes, if it does not actually have the backslashes, removing them would make the question clearer.

Comment: @BrianRogers thanks, I'm on a mobile client right now but I'll edit it when I get home

Comment: @ap I'd say your guess is correct. This looks like a bug in DropNetRT. I'd suggest opening an issue so the library developer can take a look: https://github.com/DropNet/DropNetRT/issues.

Answer (score -1):

change your string to this, it's not a valid json string http://json.parser.online.fr/

```
{
    "has_more": true,
    "cursor": "BLAGHABLAGAbigDarn-StringTHing123",
    "entries": [
        [
            "exampleFile.pdf",
            {
                "revision": 1,
                "rev": "1131aa664",
                "thumb_exists": false,
                "bytes": 249159,
                "modified": "Mon, 12 Aug 2013 18:55:30 +0000",
                "client_mtime": "Mon, 12 Aug 2013 18:55:30 +0000",
                "path": "exampleFole.pdf",
                "is_dir": false,
                "icon": "page_white_acrobat",
                "root": "dropbox",
                "mime_type": "applicationpdf",
                "size": "243.3 KB"
            }
        ],
        [
            "examplefolder",
            {
                "revision": 2,
                "rev": "2131aa664",
                "thumb_exists": false,
                "bytes": 0,
                "modified": "Tue, 13 Aug 2013 17:30:35 +0000",
                "path": "examplefolder",
                "is_dir": true,
                "icon": "folder_user",
                "root": "dropbox",
                "size": "0 bytes"
            }
        ]
    ],
    "reset": true
}
```

Comment: The JSON in the question parses fine in the tool you provided (and Python's JSON parser). Maybe the confusion is because the text in the question is copied from a debugger and thus enclosed in quotes and escaped. Unescape it first.

Comment: I was planning to use this JSON beautifier on the question. saved me the trouble